# When cloning an svn repository into git, should I clone only trunk, or the entire repo?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

What is the best practice here?

The repository in question is here: http://svn.osqa.net/svnroot/osqa/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd clone everything in the first place, just in case you need the other branches later, with:

```
git svn clone --stdlayout http://svn.osqa.net/svnroot/osqa/
```

In this case I can't see any particular reason not to, since even with all the branches a `git svn clone` of the repository only ends up being 11 megabytes.  It'll make things easier later if you are interested in the other branches.

Comment: Wait, the clone finished for you already? For me it's running for ages... :(

Comment: I didn't use the --stdlayout switch. Should I have? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361559/what-does-the-stdlayout-do-in-git-svn-clone

Comment: Cool, now that I understand --stdlayout, it seems only reasonable to clone all the branches.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm suggesting in my answer :)  If the layout of the repository is as default (which is the case with the repository you mention) then that's an easy way of grabbing all the branches and tags.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that subversion branches are exposed (usually, and in your case) via a standard naming convention of `TOPLEVEL/branches/...`. The way `git` does it is not so explicit - that is, if you do a `git checkout BRANCH_NAME`, the branch files are "swapped in" to your current working directory.

With this in mind, I'd suggest only importing trunk, and then importing all the directories in the `TOPLEVEL/branches/branchname` directory as git branches as you need them.

Comment: Did you know about --stdlayout?